# Testing HttpModule wtih Response.Filter and Response.Write

Tags: c#, integration-testing, moq

I'm working on an Http Module that simply records the response time and size and then appends the results to the response body.

My module looks something like this:

```
public override void PreRequestHandlerExecute(HttpContextBase context)
{
    // Add a filter to capture response stream
    context.Response.Filter = new ResponseSniffer(context.Response.Filter);
}

public override void ApplicationEndRequest(HttpContextBase context)
{
    ....
    context.Response.Write(builder.ToString());
}
```

I now wish to unit test this module. I'm very new to unit testing. I've adapted code from [o2platform](https://o2platform.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/mocking-httpcontext-httprequest-and-httpresponse-for-unittests-using-moq/) to get a moq httpcontext and that works so far. However, the response filter does seem to get set in Pre and the response body is what I initialized it has from the test setup.

I've tried a handful options (and read a lot of stuff) but none of these seemed to work:

```
public Mock<HttpResponseBase> MockResponse { get; set; }
...
var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
var filter = new MemoryStream();

//MockResponse.Setup(response => response.OutputStream).Returns(GetMockStream(outputStream).Object);
//MockResponse.Setup(response => response.Filter).Returns(GetMockStream(filter).Object);

MockResponse.Setup(response => response.OutputStream).Returns(() => outputStream);
//MockResponse.SetupSet(response => response.OutputStream = It.IsAny<Stream>()).Returns(() => outputStream);

MockResponse.Setup(response => response.Filter).Returns(() => filter);
MockResponse.SetupSet(response => response.Filter = It.IsAny<Stream>());
MockResponse.SetupSet(response => response.Filter = It.IsAny<ResponseSniffer>());
```

## Test Method

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var mockHttpContext = new MoqHttpContext();

    var httpContext = mockHttpContext.HttpContext();
    var html = @"<html>
                    <head></head>
                    <body>
                        <h1>Hello World</h1>
                    </body>
                </html>";

    httpContext.ResponseWrite(html);
    httpContext.StreamWrite(httpContext.Response.Filter, html);


    var module = new Module();

    module.PreRequestHandlerExecute(mockHttpContext.HttpContext());
    module.ApplicationBeginRequest(mockHttpContext.HttpContext());
    module.ApplicationEndRequest(mockHttpContext.HttpContext());

    var responseRead = httpContext.ResponseRead(); //extension method to get output stream
    var b = 1; //put breakpoint here
}
```

I realize the test needs to Assert rather then the breakpoint. I also realize that the test should be broken up a bit.

## Code Repo

[Github](https://github.com/Eonasdan/httpmodule-challenge)

Comment: I'd recommend starting off by testing the methods one at a time. If a method just adds a filter to the response, then execute the method and verify that the filter has been added. The last step in the test shouldn't be a breakpoint. It should be something that actually inspects the output and tests for some expected value. That way you don't need to hit breakpoints - you can just run the tests again and again. You'll probably find that much or even most of the setup code can be shared between the tests.

Comment: yes I know the test isn't perfect, I'm also aware that I don't need to break point, except that I'm trying to debug the test. I know I need separate test but if doesn't work as a whole it doesn't matter if it works per method

Comment: True, but the individual tests will isolate which part of the whole doesn't work.

Comment: The module works. What doesn't work is setting Response.Filter and doing the Response.Write. The output stream is the same, before and after the test. In the Test, `PreRequestHandlerExecute` the `Filter` is still a `Stream` and not a `ResponseSniffer`

Comment: Can you please share the project and related classes (e.g. on GitHub)?

Comment: @DariuszWoźniak added a link. Keep in mind this was meant to be a learning project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see at the following statement in `Module.ApplicationEndRequest()` method:

```
context.Response.Write(builder.ToString());
```

When this code is executed from Unit Test, `context.Response` is a mock that you set up in MoqHttpContext.CreateBaseMocks():

```
MockResponse = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
// ...
MockContext.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(MockResponse.Object);
```

You can't expect that you call a `Write()` method on a mock and then can read the same data back. Mock is a fake object. Its default implementation of `Write()` method does nothing, and passed data is just lost.

To fix the problem, you could setup a callback on `Response` mock that will write passed data to a stream and then return it back on read. You are actually very close to it.

In `MoqHttpContext` class declare a stream where you will save the data:

```
public class MoqHttpContext
{
    private readonly MemoryStream _outputStream = new MemoryStream();

    // ...
}
```

Then in `CreateBaseMocks()` method setup a callback:

```
public MoqHttpContext CreateBaseMocks()
{
    // ...

    MockResponse = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
    MockResponse.Setup(x => x.Write(It.IsAny<string>())).Callback<string>(s =>
    {
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
        _outputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        _outputStream.Flush();
        _outputStream.Position = 0;
    });

    // ...
}
```

You also should remove a line that sets `inputStream` position to `0` in `MoqHttpContextExtensions.StreamWrite()`, so that html data that you write in `UnitTest1.TestMethod1()` is appended, not overwritten:

```
public static HttpContextBase StreamWrite(this HttpContextBase httpContextBase, Stream inputStream, string text)
{
    if (inputStream == null) inputStream = new MemoryStream();
    var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(inputStream);

    inputStream.Position = inputStream.Length;
    streamWriter.Write(text);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    // Remove this line
    //inputStream.Position = 0;

    return httpContextBase;
}
```

That's it. Now if you check value of `responseRead` in the test, you will see that data appended by Http module is there.

**UPDATE** (Fixing problem with a filter)

There are 3 different issues with current code that prevent correct work of a filter from UT.

1. You tried handful options for mocking `Filter` property, however none of them seems correct. The correct way to mock property getter with Moq is:

   ```
   MockResponse.SetupGet(response => response.Filter).Returns(filter);
   ```

   Remove all other statements for mocking `response.Filter`, but don't add above statement yet, it's not a final version.
2. You have following check in `Module.ApplicationEndRequest()` method:

   ```
   if (context.Response.Filter is ResponseSniffer filter)
   {
       // ...
   ```

   When UT is executed, `context.Response.Filter` is a `MemoryStream` not a `ResponseSniffer`. Setter that is called in `Module` constructor:

   ```
   context.Response.Filter = new ResponseSniffer(context.Response.Filter);
   ```

   will not actually affect value returned by `Filter` getter because it's a mock that currently always return instance of `MemoryStream` that you setup with `SetupGet`. To fix this problem you should actually emulate property behavior: save the value passed to setter and return it in the getter. Here is a final setup of `response.Filter` property:

   ```
   Stream filter = new MemoryStream();
   MockResponse.SetupSet(response => response.Filter = It.IsAny<Stream>()).Callback<Stream>(value => filter = value);
   MockResponse.SetupGet(response => response.Filter).Returns(() => filter);
   ```

   Make sure you have deleted all other mocks of `response.Filter` property.
3. The final problem that you should fix - is the order of `Module` invocations from UT. Currently the order is the following:

   ```
   httpContext.StreamWrite(httpContext.Response.Filter, html);
   // ...
   var module = new Module();
   module.PreRequestHandlerExecute(mockHttpContext.HttpContext());
   ```

   But `PreRequestHandlerExecute` sets `Response.Filter` with an instance of `ResponseSniffer`. So when `httpContext.StreamWrite` above it is called, `httpContext.Response.Filter` holds actually instance of `MemoryStream`, not `ResponseSniffer`. So the last fix you should make is to change the order of statements in UT body:

   ```
   // ...

   var module = new Module();
   module.PreRequestHandlerExecute(mockHttpContext.HttpContext());

   httpContext.ResponseWrite(html);
   httpContext.StreamWrite(httpContext.Response.Filter, html);

   module.ApplicationBeginRequest(mockHttpContext.HttpContext());
   module.ApplicationEndRequest(mockHttpContext.HttpContext());

   // ...
   ```

**UPDATE** (UT Redesign)

At this point your UT should work. However current test is very cumbersome. The fact that it takes so much time to understand why it does not work proves it. Such tests are very hard to maintain and fix, they become a real pain over time.

Moreover it's rather Integration test than Unit test, because it invokes several of classes with different functionality - `ResponseSniffer` and `Module`.

You should strongly consider redesign of current test. And the good start is to make separate tests for `ResponseSniffer` and `Module` classes.

Most valuable test for `ResponseSniffer` is the one that verifies that written data is registered in `RecordStream`:

```
[TestClass]
public class ResponseSnifferTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Write_WritesDataToRecordStream()
    {
        //  Arrange

        var inData = new byte[] { 0x01 };

        var target = new ResponseSniffer(Mock.Of<Stream>());

        //  Act

        target.Write(inData, 0, inData.Length);

        //  Assert

        target.RecordStream.Position = 0;
        var outData = new byte[inData.Length];
        int outSize = target.RecordStream.Read(outData, 0, outData.Length);
        Assert.AreEqual(inData.Length, outSize);
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(inData, outData);
    }
}
```

As regards `Module` class, there are several checks that should be made:

- `PreRequestHandlerExecute()` sets `Response.Filter` with instance of `ResponseSniffer`.
- `ApplicationBeginRequest()` adds `Stopwatch` to `context.Items` dictionary.
- `ApplicationEndRequest()` writes request info to the response.

UT approach implies checking of these facts in separate tests. Here are samples of such 3 tests:

```
[TestClass]
public class ModuleTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void PreRequestHandlerExecuteShouldSetResponseSnifferAsFilter()
    {
        //  Arrange

        Stream filter = null;
        Mock<HttpResponseBase> httpResponseMock = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        httpResponseMock.SetupSet(response => response.Filter = It.IsAny<Stream>()).Callback<Stream>(value => filter = value);

        Mock<HttpContextBase> httpContextStub = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        httpContextStub.SetupGet(x => x.Response).Returns(httpResponseMock.Object);

        var target = new Module();

        //  Act

        target.PreRequestHandlerExecute(httpContextStub.Object);

        //  Assert

        Assert.IsNotNull(filter);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(filter, typeof(ResponseSniffer));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ApplicationBeginRequestShouldStoreStopwatchInContextItems()
    {
        //  Arrange

        var items = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        Mock<HttpContextBase> httpContextStub = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        httpContextStub.SetupGet(x => x.Items).Returns(items);

        var target = new Module();

        //  Act

        target.ApplicationBeginRequest(httpContextStub.Object);

        //  Assert

        Assert.IsTrue(items.ContainsKey("X-ResponseTime"));
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(items["X-ResponseTime"], typeof(Stopwatch));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ApplicationEndRequestShouldAddRequestInfoToResponse()
    {
        //  Arrange

        Mock<HttpRequestBase> httpRequestMock = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        httpRequestMock.SetupGet(x => x.FilePath).Returns("/test");

        string writtenData = null;
        Mock<HttpResponseBase> httpResponseMock = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        httpResponseMock.Setup(x => x.Write(It.IsAny<string>())).Callback<string>(s => writtenData = s);

        Mock<HttpContextBase> httpContextStub = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        httpContextStub.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(httpRequestMock.Object);
        httpContextStub.SetupGet(x => x.Response).Returns(httpResponseMock.Object);
        httpContextStub.SetupGet(x => x.Items).Returns(new Dictionary<string, object> { ["X-ResponseTime"] = new Stopwatch() });

        var target = new Module();

        //  Act

        target.ApplicationEndRequest(httpContextStub.Object);

        //  Assert

        Assert.IsTrue(Regex.IsMatch(writtenData, @"Response Size: \d+ bytes<br/>"));
        Assert.IsTrue(Regex.IsMatch(writtenData, @"Module request time: \d+ ms"));
    }
}
```

As you see, the tests are pretty simple and straightforward. You don't need those `MoqHttpContext` and `MoqHttpContextExtensions` with a lot of mocks and helpers anymore. Another benefit - if some of the tests get broken, it's much easier to identify the root cause and fix it.

If you are new to Unit Testing and are looking for good source of info on it, I strongly suggest book [The Art of Unit Testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617290890) by Roy Osherove.

Comment: `StreamWrite` is an extension method from the o2platform link. Looks like I was close. I did get `ApplicationEndRequest` to work in the test thanks to you. Your answer does not however, address the question of `context.Response.Filter = ` I'm assuming this is a similar issue but what does the setting a property in moq look like?

Comment: I had done `MockResponse.SetupSet(response => response.Filter = It.IsAny<Stream>())` and `MockResponse.SetupSet(response => response.Filter = It.IsAny<ResponseSniffer>())` but that seems to be still missing something

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll check out that book. A lot of projects I've been on have been always been "wouldn't it be nice to testing" but not much further lol. I can see the advantage of the `MoqHttpContext` however as this is meant to be a simple module, it's probably not needed.